# Replacing halogen under-cabinet lights - connection question

Tags: electrical, kitchens, connectors

I'm replacing some old halogen under-cabinet lights but am not sure how to connect the new LED replacements.

The old halogen lights had the following connector which is not compatible with the new lights:

[image: Old connector]

The new connection looks like this, and in turn connects to an LED power supply which then connects to the new lights:

[image: New connector]

My question is, can I just cut the plug off the new cable and wire it into the circular connection box, the contents of which looks like this:

[image]

I realise doing this will remove the fuse from the circuit, but is that an issue? Is it safe to assume that the connection into the connection box above is fused in some way?

Comment: you can likely dremel a notch in the old plug to let it fit into the new socket; it's just a minor physical adaption.

Comment: I'm not certain of all the details of UK wiring regulations, but I'd think you'd be better off removing that circular box and installing a receptacle that you can plug the new lights into, instead. The new receptacle could be surface mount (like this old box) or flush mount, depending on code, work involved & budget.

Comment: @FreeMan - what would the benefit of that be? And by 'plugging the new lights into' do you mean plugging the LED power supply or the just connecting the lights directly?

Comment: @dandavis - the hole sizes are slightly different on the two connectors. If I were to cut the plug off the new cord and wire it into the box would that have the same effect?

Comment: sure, that will work. might be easier to try applying unreasonable force first though, depending on how slight "slighty" is...

Comment: Your 2nd picture seems to show a power lead that goes from a mains socket to a 2-pin connector. I presume that 2-pin "figure 8" connector is what goes into your new LED power supply, and then something goes from the power supply to the new LEDs you're installing. Replacing the round fitting on the wall with a socket that the cable in your hand can plug into allows you to install your new lights without modifying any of the hardware that comes with them. Generally, cutting the plug off the lead with A) void your warranty, and B) is (I believe) not legal (in the US, at least).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cutting an extra notch into the existing plug allowed it to fit into the new socket and that worked a treat.